# How do I correctly install the AMD Radeon proprietary GPU driver on 18.04?

Tags: drivers, graphics, radeon, amd-graphics

I've recently reinstalled my system from 14.04 to 18.04 and noticed that the proprietary driver for AMD GPUs is no longer available from the official sources. This comes with some issues: E.g. I can't run a few programs anymore with the open source driver and it doesn't load my display's color profile.

I'd like to install the proprietary AMD driver, but the [AMD driver download website](https://support.amd.com/en-us/kb-articles/Pages/AMD-Radeon-GPU-PRO-Linux-Beta-Driver%E2%80%93Release-Notes.aspx) only shows 16.04 as supported.

Is this even the correct driver that is needed and will it work on 18.04? Is there another way to install a supported driver?